# Log box with text input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a log box with a text input and a submit button. I can get it to display entered text with

```
var test = function() {
var test1 = document.getElementById('input');
var totalTest = test1.value;
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += totalTest; 
};
```

But I cant get it to respond to it. I want to keep asking questions and all answers come from one input box. I am very new still to JavaScript, and would love anyone's help.
Here is all I have so far. JAVASCRIPT:

```
var playerInput = function () {
var pInput = document.getElementById('input');
var input = pInput.value;
};

var playerNum = function () { //Choice between Single and Multiplayer
     document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "Would you like to play singleplayer or    multiplayer?";
oneOrTwo(input);
};

var oneOrTwo = function (input) {
    var playerAmount = input;
    if (playerAmount == "singleplayer") {
        //singlePlay();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "Multiplayer is coming soon";
        //multiPlay();
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Rock Paper Scissors, with Single and Multiplayer! </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logHeader">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; font-family: calibri;"> Rock, Paper, Scissors </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <br >
    <input id="input" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value=='Type here') this.value='';" style="border: 2px solid; width: 300px; background-color: lightblue;" value="Type here">
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="test()">
    <br >
    <br >
    <input type="button" onclick="playerNum()" value="Start Game">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really all you need to change is to move the `oneOrTwo(input)` call up to your `playerInput()` function.

It doesn't make sense to try to read the input right away after asking the question; the user won't have time to respond.

```
var playerNum = function () { //Choice between Single and Multiplayer
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "Would you like to play singleplayer or multiplayer?";
    //nothing else, read the input later
};
```

When the player enters a response and clicks the 'Enter' button, **then** try to read the input:

```
var playerInput = function () {
    var pInput = document.getElementById('input');
    var input = pInput.value;
    oneOrTwo(input);
};
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="playerInput()">
```

Threw it into a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KfUp8/

Answer (score 1):

`var input = pInput.value;` stores the value of your input into that variable.

It will never change unless you execute that same line again.

Replace `oneOrTwo(input);` with `oneOrTwo(pInput.value);` to get a fresh value every time.

Comment: This should work, but now my problem is I need to run    `oneOrTwo(pInput.value);` after I push the enter button.

Comment: @Gateway12231 You already are. Pressing the submit button runs `playerNum` which calls `oneOrTwo`.  Just replace `input` with `pInput.value` and it will work every time you press the button.